# Inverse of the asymptotic expansion of Gauss Hypergeometric function

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, inverse-function, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in obtaining the asymptotic expansion of $r(\rho)$ (which is the inverse of $\rho$ below). Basically I want to series expand $\rho$ for large $r$ (i.e. as $r\to \infty$) and then invert the series to obtain $r(\rho)$. I have tried some readily available asymptotic expansion of $_2F_1$ but I think I ruined my calculations and I am not really sure if I am doing the right thing. By the way, $b$ is just some positive constant while $-\infty<q<1$.

$$\rho=\frac{2b}{1-q}\left(1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)^{1/2}\left(_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{q-1},\frac{3}{2},1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Your function isn't analytic at $1/r=0$, it has a branch point with something like $r^{-1/2}$ and $r^{1-3/2-1+1/(q-1)}$ terms

Comment: What then can I do with the function? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need an asymptotic for ${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}(a, b; c; z)$ with $z \to 1^-$. Since $c - a - b = 1/(q - 1) < 0$, the leading term is
$$\frac {\Gamma(c) \Gamma(a + b - c)} {\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)} (1 - z)^{c - a - b}.$$
This gives $\rho \sim r \sqrt{1 - (b/r)^{1 - q}}$, therefore $\rho \sim r$ and $r \sim \rho$.

For $q < 0$, the next term in the expansion of ${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}$ is a constant, and we need only the first term from the $(1 - z)^{1/2}$ factor:
$${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}
 {\left( \frac 1 2, p; \frac 3 2; 1 - z \right)} =
\frac {z^{1 - p}} {2 (p - 1)} +
 \frac {\sqrt \pi \,\Gamma(1 - p)}
  {2 \Gamma {\left( \frac 3 2 - p \right)}} + \dots, \\
\rho = r + \frac {b \sqrt \pi \,\Gamma(1 - p)}
 {(1 - q) \Gamma {\left( \frac 3 2 - p \right)}} + \dots, \\
r = \rho - \frac {b \sqrt \pi \,\Gamma(1 - p)}
 {(1 - q) \Gamma {\left( \frac 3 2 - p \right)}} + \dots,$$
where $p = (2 - q)/(1 - q)$. For $q > 0$ and excluding the logarithmic case $p \in \mathbb N$, the next term in the expansion of ${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}$ is of order $z^{2 - p}$, and we need two terms from $(1 - z)^{1/2}$:
$${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}
 {\left( \frac 1 2, p; \frac 3 2; 1 - z \right)} =
\frac {z^{1 - p}} {2 (p - 1)} +
\frac {(2 p - 3) z^{2 - p}} {4 (p - 1) (p - 2)} + \dots, \\
\rho = r + \frac {b^{1 - q} r^q} {2 q} + \dots, \\
r = \rho - \frac {b^{1 - q} \rho^q} {2 q} + \dots,$$
the last step coming from the [Lagrange reversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88485/discussion-on-answer-by-maxim-inverse-of-the-asymptotic-expansion-of-gauss-hyper).

Comment: @Maxim, why did you split the analysis into $q<0$ and $q>0$? In my numerical test of the magnitude of terms in the expansion, it seems that the constant in the expansion is practically zero (or has negative value) for all $q<0$ . And I guess all the correction terms come from the terms in parenthesis with the leading order.

Comment: How can I obtain for the third term in the expansion? Thanks