# Correction terms in the asymptotics of hypergeometric function

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, inverse-function, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in obtaining the asymptotic expansion of $r(\rho)$ $($which is the inverse of $\rho$ below$)$,

$$\rho=\frac{2b}{1-q}\left(1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)^{1/2}\left(_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{q-1},\frac{3}{2},1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)\right)$$

where $b$ is just some positive constant while $-\infty<q<1$.

Basically I want to series expand $\rho$ for large $r$ $($i.e. as $r\to \infty$$)$ and then invert the series to obtain $r(\rho)$. I have tried some [readily available asymptotic expansion of $_2F_1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/06/01/04/01/01/0003/).

Basically I got,

$$\rho\sim r\sqrt{1-(b/r)^{1-q}}$$

as the leading term in the expansion. Is there a detailed easy way of finding the next two correction terms in the expansion, given the allowed values of $q$? Thank you.

Comment: The first two terms are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3010108).

Comment: @Maxim It seems to me like the linked question is nearly the same as the now posted, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes they are the same. But I made another question for determining the second correction term. I am puzzled on how to obtain the next correction to the expansion. @Maxim, can you help me work out the next term because it seems I need an extra term. Thanks